# Keep display in sleep mode and ignore input

Tags: c#, windows, screen, mouse, standby

i am programming a C# app. 
I want to set my screen to sleep mode and wake it up again manual.
So far no problem. I am using SC_MONITORPOWER 2 to shut it off and -1 to switch the screen on again.

My Problem is: As soon as i touch the (touch)screen or click the mouse - the screen switches on. Is there any possibility to force the system to ignore user input or to keep the screen off until i am doing it via SC_MONITORPOWER again.

Power saving option like sleep screen after x minutes is not an option.

System is Windows 10 Enterprise 1604

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if your application dies while it's in sleep? The approach seems like a recipe for frustration to me.

Comment: @itsme86 Thank you for your comment. This is a very good Point. But i think i have a special use case at which this makes sense and the application makes use of an hardware watchdog which power cycles the system if it crashes. And if the system reboots the screen is switched off again via SC_MONITORPOWER - but - i need to keep it in sleep until i manual wake it up. Imagine a touch kiosk system outside the runtime (at night) and someone touching it anyway. In my case the screen would switch on an the backlight of the screen is visible and costing energy. (The whole night until runtime begin)